# Is it possible to activate or deactivate jobs via a configuration file so as to avoid unintentional startups?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, quartz

I would like to have the possibility to activate or deactivate jobs via:

- a configuration file with specific `ON`/`OFF` for each job or
- a mysql table with specific `ON`/`OFF` for each job.

Charging must take place at each change of status: for example, if a job is `OFF` when the `ON` setting (state change) the java app will be able to receive the status update.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: please show your effort

Comment: What do you call job?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for capability to control your jobs from configuration. If yes, then following might be helpful.

You can schedule you jobs using Apache Camel routing.

```
public class JobExecutorRoute extends RouteBuilder
{   
  private String script="exec:yourjob.sh";
  private String cron="quartz2://group/timer?cron=00+00+010+*+*+?" ;

  public void configure() throws Exception {        
            from(script).autoStartup(true).to(cron);
    }
}
```